# Changes listener script to run on a server in the background?

Tags: python, event-listener

I've written the python script below to run on a server, and act as a listener for changes in a json response from a URI api.

```
import json import time
import requests

class Test():

   def __init__(self):
       self.total_services = self.__get_total_services()

   def __get_total_services(self):
       url = "my_url_that_responds_with_json"
       response = requests.get(url)
       json_data = response.json()
       dict_data = json.loads(json.dumps(json_data))
       total = len(dict_data['services'])
       return total

   def listen_for_changes(self):
      while 1:
           if (self.__get_total_services() != self.total_services):
               """do something"""
               self.total_services = self.__get_total_services()
           time.sleep(60)
       return 0

my_test = Test()
my_test.listen_for_changes()
```

My question is should this code run somehow in the background or it is ok to run it like this from my server?

Comment: well it will consume a thread, if you have extra threads sitting around you can use it on your own server.

Comment: how would be an alternative implementation?